# Time taken by trigger for GetDate vs time taken for Milliseconds in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, getdate

I was doing the performance test of GetDate vs milliseconds in SQL. I run a trigger which inserts current time in field on update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDate ON sm_activity 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE sm_activity SET LastUpdate = GETDATE()
   FROM sm_activity INNER JOIN inserted i ON 
   i.id =sm_activity.id
END
```

And run update query on 10000 rows. It took 34431 milliseconds while when I used milliseconds in trigger that is

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDate ON sm_activity 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE sm_activity SET LastUpdate = (CAST(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS date)) AS bigint)*1000) + DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS date), GETUTCDATE()) 
   FROM sm_activity INNER JOIN inserted i ON 
   i.id =sm_activity.id
END
```

For the same number of rows, it took 15124 milliseconds. How is it possible that GetDate() is taking double of milliseconds even though milliseconds are being calculated by using GetDate.

Comment: I'd look at what your trigger is actually spending time doing with extended events. My gut feeling says that you happened to wait longer for locks with the first version than the second. Also, those numbers look suspiciously like you ran each version once. Try running them multiple times and average the results - you're less likely to succumb to one-off situations that aren't under your control.

Comment: i have checked it multiple times. it was approximately same.